# Public bucket requires user to be logged in

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I have a GCP bucket which is intended to be readable by all users. The purpose of this bucket is to host images for a website.

I am using [uniform bucket-level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access), and I have given `allUsers` and `allAuthenticatedUsers` access to the bucket.

Here is the output of `gsutil iam get` (some information is redacted):

```
$ gsutil iam get gs://my-bucket
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "user:admin@company.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.admin"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "projectEditor:my-project",
        "projectOwner:my-project",
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "allAuthenticatedUsers",
        "allUsers",
        "projectViewer:my-project",
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "user:admin@company.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.objectAdmin"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "allAuthenticatedUsers",
        "allUsers",
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.objectViewer"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "<redacted>"
}
```

Note that `allUsers` and `allAuthenticatedUsers` have the role `roles/storage.objectViewer`.

However, when I try to access one of these objects, I'm presented with a sign in page. I can then sign in as *any user* and access the object. It's almost like GCP is ignoring the `allUsers` directive and using `allAuthenticatedUsers`, but I don't understand why it would do that.

To access the object, I'm using a URL which looks like this:

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucket/path/to/file.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of the below formats for url formation of object in the bucket to access 
without getting logged in

`http(s)://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>`

`http(s)://<bucket>.storage.googleapis.com/<object>`